# Swift - set up number of rows from a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary defined as:

```
var episodesDictionary = [String: [Episode]]()
```

Each item in the dictionary can have a certain number of episodes, for example:

```
title1: episode1, episode2, episode3
title2: episode1, episode2
title3: episode1, episode2, episode3, episode4
```

What I want is to set up a table. So in numberofSectionsInTableView I return

```
episodesDictionary.count
```

The problem is I don't know how to get the number of rows for each section. I tried the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var episodes = [Int]()

    for (key, value) in episodesDictionary {
        var shows = [String]()
        shows.append(key)
        episodes.append(value.count)
    }

    return episodes[section]

}
```

But I always get 0

The episodesDictionary is being parsed from a JSON file obtained from a server.

Any ideas on how I can manage to set up the rows for each section?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want an array of Ints corresponding to the number of episodes in each section?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries don't preserve ordering of their key-value pairs. Thus, you can't make an array whose elements correspond to the number of episodes of the corresponding title, because they're no guarantee the dictionary will be enumerated in sorted order as you would expect.

Instead, you would need to make a dictionary from titles to numbers of episodes:

```
let episodes = [
    "title1" : ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3"],
    "title2" : ["episode1", "episode2"],
    "title3" : ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3", "episode4"],
]

let episodeCounts = episodes.mapValues { $0.count }

print(episodeCounts) //prints ["title1": 3, "title2": 2, "title3": 4]
```

#### Prior to Swift 4

There was no `mapValues`, so you had to write this yourself:

```
let dict = [
    "title1" : ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3"],
    "title2" : ["episode1", "episode2"],
    "title3" : ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3", "episode4"],
]

var episodeCounts = [String : Int]()

for (title, episodes) in dict {
    episodeCounts[title] = episodes.count
}

print(episodeCounts) //prints ["title1": 3, "title2": 2, "title3": 4]
```

Comment: @AnuragSharma This isn't actually the best way to do it anymore. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating .. :)

Comment: @AnuragSharma Done

Comment: but it is saying Cannot convert return expression of type '[String : Int]' to return type 'Int' for the first example, but second one is working

Comment: @AnuragSharma In both cases, `episodeCounts` is a `[String : Int]`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the dictionary you're using might not be the best choice. Try using a tuple, like:

```
let elements: [(title: String, episodes: [String])] = [
    ("title1", ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3"]),
    ("title2", ["episode1", "episode2"]),
    ("title3", ["episode1", "episode2", "episode3", "episode4"]),
]
```

which would let you handle numberOfRowsInSection like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return elements[section].episodes.count
}
```